# Android: Update Array of Strings from file online

Tags: android, arrays, updating

I am developing an android app that uses nostra13 library. First, nostra13 uses a class file that contains array of strings which are the urls of the images to be downloaded.

ex.

```
public static final String[] IMAGES = new String[]{
    "http://www.ltp.com.ph/SiteImages/Technilink/TL_1Q13_CE.jpg",
    "http://www.ltp.com.ph/SiteImages/Technilink/TL_4Q12_CE.jpg",
    "http://www.ltp.com.ph/SiteImages/Technilink/TL_2Q12_CE.jpg",
    "http://www.ltp.com.ph/SiteImages/Technilink/TL_1Q12_CE.jpg",
    "http://www.ltp.com.ph/SiteImages/Technilink/TL_4Q11_CE.jpg",
    "http://www.ltp.com.ph/SiteImages/Technilink/TL_2Q11_CE.jpg",
    "http://www.ltp.com.ph/SiteImages/Technilink/TL_1Q11_CE.jpg",
    "http://www.ltp.com.ph/SiteImages/Technilink/TL_4Q10_CE.jpg"
};
```

Is there a way to update this string array online? Like I want to put some file online then the app would download it and update the String[] IMAGES? THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the value stored in each array position with new data obtained on-line, but you would not be able to change the length of the array because it is declared `final`.

A better approach is to think of the `IMAGES` array as the source of data for initializing your working array, which you could store in persistent store (e.g., `SharedPreferences` or SQLite data base—see the guide topic [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)). When you retrieve new data from the web, you can then easily replace or update the stored data. You would only use the `IMAGES` array to initialize your working array and ignore it after that (unless you added a "reset" function to return to the original data).

Comment: Thanks! can i do something like public static final String[] IMAGES = new String[] .... then pass db values to IMAGES?

Comment: @KenndeLeon - When you declare a `final` array, the array object that you assign to it cannot be changed; you can only change the elements stored in the array. If you want to protect the array from inadvertent changes from other code, make it a (non-`final`) private member of a small utility class (probably a singleton would be best) that provides accessors and setters for manipulating the values in a controlled way. The utility class can also be made responsible for interacting with the db, if that fits with the rest of the design, or you can have a bulk change setter method.